# Does Powerpoint 2003 work with Keynote

Tags: keynote, ms-office

I have created a presentation in Powerpoint 2003 and have opened it in Keynote, however, when I veiw the presentation on the iPad the colors in the graphs have changed as well as the font alignment.  Is there a way to fix this so that it looks the same in Powerpoint and Keynote?  Is there a different version of Powerpoint that would work better?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Keynote and Powerpoint do not talk to each other all that well. A lot of formatting issues have been known to occur.

If you're wanting to view/edit/present the presentation on your iPad, I would suggest using Keynote on your Mac and Keynote on your iPad. If you're wanting to stay as compatible with a Windows environment as possible, I would suggest using QuickOffice HD on the iPad and Microsoft Office for Mac 2011.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, Keynote on the iPad does not support the same array of colors, fonts, and styles as the Mac version, so that could be an issue as well.